# Python-chain.from_iterable returns memory address instead of value

Tags: python, python-itertools, chain

I'm trying to write a simple program for taking in a set of elements and printing out the powerset.

I'm using the recipe for a powerset function as given in python's documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html

For some reason instead of returning values, it returns the memory address of a itertools.chain object.

Why is it doing this?

```
from itertools import chain,combinations
def pwrst(iter):
    xs = list(iter)
    return chain.from_iterable( combinations(xs,n) for n in range(len(xs)+1))
s = input("Enter elements seperated by comma: ")
il = s(',')
ss = [int(x.strip()) for x in il]
pwrst(ss)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chain.from_iterable` returns an iterable **object** (whose default `__repr__` tells you the memory address).  You actually have to iterate over it to get the values.  e.g.:

```
list(pwrst(ss))
```

Under normal circumstances, you might do something like:

```
for item in pwrst(ss):
    ...
```